# SQL - How to eliminate duplicate weeks when grouping by week and month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

My latest confusion is this...
I've writen a query that shows average billing value by week over time and I'm using the start of the week to define which week the billing falls in to - it works fine as a query but I'm having trouble with charts in Excel/SSMS where a month starts in a week from the previous month.
Example: 1st July 2020 is in the week begining 26th June so where I get a June entry for 06/29 and a July entry for 06/29, the two billing avereges are added together by excel/SSMS charts.

How do I get around that and show the data within it's correct month? (so July 1st is in the 1st week of July rather than the last week of June).

Here's my script...

```
select top 999999999999
Avg(net) as 'AveNet', Year, Month, [Week_Start_Date]


from
(
select
FORMAT([InvDate], 'MMM', 'en-US')+ '-' + right(year(invdate),2) as 'Month',
day(invdate) as 'Day',
datepart(yyyy,invdate) as 'Year',
datepart(week,invdate) as 'WkNum',
invdate,
DATEADD(DAY, 2 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, invdate), CAST(invdate AS DATE)) [Week_Start_Date],
net

from DB_consolsalesview csv
where invdate > '20190930'

) daily

group by Year,Week_Start_Date, month

Order by 
Year, Week_Start_Date
```

Results...

```
AveNet      Year    Month   Week_Start_Date
...
1004.834000 2020    May-20  2020-04-27
864.347407  2020    May-20  2020-05-04
725.336176  2020    May-20  2020-05-11
613.252777  2020    May-20  2020-05-18
702.085128  2020    May-20  2020-05-25
634.586363  2020    Jun-20  2020-06-01
750.134166  2020    Jun-20  2020-06-08
599.930857  2020    Jun-20  2020-06-15
845.304687  2020    Jun-20  2020-06-22
897.033000  2020    Jul-20  2020-06-29
669.337812  2020    Jun-20  2020-06-29
```

Comment: So what are your expected results here exactly, and what is your sample data? Also, 2008 has been completely unsupported for a year now, and you should really be looking at upgrade paths.

Comment: I'll update the question - I need all data withing one month to show in its own month - so July 1st in a 'July' week rather than in the last week of June.

Comment: ...and it's SQL 2012 - my mistake!

Comment: The problem is, as you said, you are breaking up you measure of by week for by month as you move over the end of the month.
So the question is then, Do you have display you output / avg by weeks and a 2nd table & query of avg by month? This would make more sense as a 7 day avg then once in a while an avg of 3 days will not provide accurate stats for the business.

Answer (score 0):

You said "I'm using the start of the week to define which week the billing falls in to", but I think you must have meant "I'm using the start of the week to define which *month* the billing falls in to".

In other words, in order to group any date properly into the month, for any given date you want to find the first day of the week, and then find the month of that first day.

You need to define what you want the "first day of the week" to be. Monday, or Sunday, or some other day? This is defined by the value of `@@datefirst`, and can be changed for a session using `set datefirst`

Assuming you want the week to start on Monday, getting the first day of the week for any arbitrary date @d can be found using:

```
select dateadd(ww, datediff(ww, 0, @d), 0)
```

Which uses the "trick" of finding out how many weeks have elapsed between the "zero date", and the date `@d`, and then adds that many weeks to the zero date. Since the zero date is a monday, this only works if you want monday to be the start of the week.

You can then get the month of that day by wrapping that expression in `datepart(month ...`

```
select datepart(month, dateadd(ww, datediff(ww, 0, @d), 0))
```

Answer (score -1):

I think i've solved this.

I added the following...

```
case 
when Month(DATEADD(DAY, 2 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, invdate), CAST(invdate AS DATE))) = 
Month(invdate) -1 then DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Invdate), 0) 
else 

DATEADD(DAY, 2 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, invdate), CAST(invdate AS DATE)) end as 
[Week_Start_Date],
```

If the week start date month is equal to the transaction date month minus 1, then use the first day of the month for that transaction.